# Solace Interface - Rx Bad Frames

Tags: solace, solace-mq

What is mean of  Rx Bad Frames &  Rx Oversize Frames ?

Rx Bad Frames &  Rx Oversize Frames count is showing 2, in Solace Appliance after executing Show Interface X/X/X Details commend.

PFB, Output of Show Interface X/X/X Details.

```
 ************************** Ingress Statistics *****************************

  Rx MAC Stats:
    Rx Good Frames                                                50328462546
    Rx BCast Frames                                                  43834352
    Rx MCast Frames                                                   7717659
    Rx 64B Frames                                                 23436379927
    Rx 65B To 127B Frames                                          2400044742
---Press any key to continue, or `q' to quit---
    Rx 128B To 255B Frames                                         9695430185
    Rx 256B To 511B Frames                                         3765946451
    Rx 512B To 1023B Frames                                         919845590
    Rx 1024B To 1518B Frames                                      10110815651
    Rx Jumbo Frames                                                         0
    Rx Oversize Frames                                                      2
    Rx Undersize Frames                                                     0
    Rx Runt Errors                                                          0
    Rx Jabbers                                                              0
    Rx MAC Ctrl Frames                                                      0
    Rx Bad Frames                                                           2
```

As per my understanding , its something related to Cabling part.

Please advise, If there any action need to perform.

Answer (score 0):

The interface has received 2 erroneous Ethernet frames, with a size that is too large.

2 errors out of 50328462546 good frames is not a cause for concern.
However, you should continue to monitor whether this statistic is increasing in the event that there is an actual hardware problem, such as a faulty Ethernet cable.